# Python Saving files in different folders

Tags: python

I created files within a function in a class and the files are saved at the same path than the code file but i want to save them into different folders,

```
save_path = raw_input("give save path. like '/home/user/dalbums'")
album = raw_input("the name of album: ")
completeName = os.path.join(save_path,album)
if not os.path.exists(completeName):
    os.makedirs(completeName)

class X:
    def saver(my, info):
        with open(completeName +'/file2/save.txt','a') as f:
            for i in info:
                f.write(info)
        lo = info[0]
        with open(completeName +'/file1/txt.txt','a') as f:
             for i in lo:
                 f.write(lo)
```

Comment: please describe what the problem is (does the code above not work? etc) / what you already tried

Comment: you need to first create folders `file1` and `file2`

Answer (score 0):

You already ensured the path stored in `completeName` exists on disk... Do the same for your 2 subfolders:

```
save_path = raw_input("give save path. like '/home/user/dalbums'")
album = raw_input("the name of album: ")
completeName = os.path.join(save_path,album)

file2_path = os.path.join(completeName , 'file2')
file1_path = os.path.join(completeName , 'file1')

if not os.path.exists(file2_path):
    os.makedirs(file2_path)
if not os.path.exists(file1_path):
    os.makedirs(file1_path)

class X:
    def saver(my, info):
        with open(file2_path  +'/save.txt','a') as f:
            for i in info:
                f.write(info)
        lo = info[0]
        with open(file1_path + '/txt.txt','a') as f:
             for i in lo:
                 f.write(lo)
```

Comment: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\ss\\path_name\\txt.txt\\a'

Comment: you probably tried to use os.path.join() but introduced a mistake with parenthesis

Comment: let me guess: `open(os.path.join(file1_path, '/txt.txt', 'a'))` instead of `open(os.path.join(file1_path, '/txt.txt'), 'a')`

Comment: Sorry once thing I am actually parsing images into the newly created folder every thing works well but then at some point it gives an error No such file or directory: even thought there are several imgs were prased into the same   directory

Comment: It's impossible to help you with this new problem without more information. Ask a new question to describe this new issue, and don't forget to post the code, the full error messages and the traceback you got

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148020/discussion-between-antwane-and-pro).

Answer (score 0):

You need create the full directories:

```
import os


class X:
    def saver(self, info):
        path_name = os.path.join(completeName, 'file2')
        if not os.path.exists(path_name):
            os.makedirs(path_name)
        with open(os.path.join(path_name, 'save.txt'), 'a') as f:
            for i in info:
                f.write(info)
        lo = info[0]
        path_name = os.path.join(completeName, 'file1')
        if not os.path.exists(path_name):
            os.makedirs(path_name)
        with open(os.path.join(path_name, 'txt.txt'), 'a') as f:
             for i in lo:
                 f.write(lo)
```

Comment: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\ss\\path_name\\txt.txt\\a'